# How to mock an unexported function in javascript jest?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a module in my vuejs project that i want to test

```
import { getBaseUrl } from "@/application/api/baseUrl";

export default (
  uri: string,
  requestBody: Record<string, string | number>
): void => {
  let form = document.createElement("form");

  form.method = "POST";
  form.action = `${getBaseUrl()}/${uri}`;

  form = convertToFormData(form, requestBody);
  submitForm(form);
};

function convertToFormData(
  form: HTMLFormElement,
  requestBody: Record<string, string | number>
) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(requestBody)) {
    const element = document.createElement("input");
    element.name = key;
    element.value = value.toString();
    form.appendChild(element);
  }
  return form;
}

function submitForm(form: HTMLFormElement) {
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

I want to test this behavior but I don't want it to actually redirect, so i want to mock `submitForm` with a simple `jest.fn()` so that i can check it's behaviour.

I tried to implement rewire using babel for ts but i can't get it to work with the new vue-cli 5.*. These babel packages also seem to be abandoned. Is there another way to test this beheviour?

my test at this point:

```
import postRedirect from "@/application/util/postRedirect";

const submitFormMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock("@/application/util/postRedirect", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@/application/util/postRedirect'),
  submitForm: submitFormMock,
}));


describe("PostRedirect", () => {
  it("", () => {
    postRedirect("test", { foo: "bar", baz: "foo" });

    expect(submitFormMock).toBeCalled();
    const formDataObject = {} as Record<string, unknown>;

    for (const [key, value] of new FormData(
      submitFormMock.mock.calls[0][0]
    ).entries()) {
      formDataObject[key] = value;
    }

    expect(formDataObject.foo).toBe("bar");
    expect(formDataObject.baz).toBe("foo");
  });
});
```

I try to mock `submitForm` but this isn't the way to go, perhaps anyone else knows how to mock this correctly.

update:
I'm currently also trying to just export the submitForm anyway even if it's not ment to be exported, but I can't get that to work either.
since I have to mock only one named export and not the default export

Comment: You don't. Unexported functions are _private_, they're implementation details.

Comment: So you are saying that you may not test private functions? A unit test should test the whole export? 
If so, how would you test this without getting the error `Error: Not implemented: HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit` because you cant do a redirect in jest?

Comment: You can test private functions but you don't do so _directly_, you test them via the public API of the module they're in (i.e. the functions that _are_ exported). Wanting to use a test double suggests that you want to isolate some part of the behaviour, in which case it should be extracted to a _separate_ module. But what you're doing seems a little weird - I haven't used Vue for a while but it's unusual in _any_ of the SPA frameworks to interfere with the DOM yourself.

Comment: It's correct that this is not very vue like. What i'm trying to do is just redirect the user to another application using a post. It's part of the API's authorisation logic that the user is redirected to the api and that api sends it back to the SPA with a token, so i don't have any controll on that.

What i want to test is, that if this function is called that it's redirecting the user with the correct post values. 

perhaps there is a better way to redirect the user using a POST call, but i cant think of any?

Answer (score 0):

With a little inspiration of @jonrsharpe i created a new test with the idee that i should not test private methods.

I still find it a little dirty but this is a way of testing that when I call my function that does a redirect using a POST call, that it actually does a submit and that it does have the right attributes in the form that was created.

I'm open for other opinions and ways of testing this, or of ways to redirect the user with a post to another application.

```
import postRedirect from "@/application/util/postRedirect";

describe("PostRedirect", () => {
  it("", () => {
    const mockSubmit = jest.fn();
    window.HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = mockSubmit
    postRedirect("test", { foo: "bar", baz: "foo" });
    expect(mockSubmit).toBeCalled();

    // @ts-ignore
    const values = Array.from(new FormData(document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0] as HTMLFormElement));
    
    expect(values[0][0]).toBe("foo");
    expect(values[0][1]).toBe("bar");
    expect(values[1][0]).toBe("baz");
    expect(values[1][1]).toBe("foo");
  });
});
```